# Jenkins, git, submodules with custom URL (SSH)

Tags: git, ssh, jenkins

Problem is simple: the main git repository can be accessed by Jenkins with **ssh://ci_ro@server** (works well), but I have submodules whose URL is different: **ssh://server** (without defining some user, this is to allow developers to work with this repo and its submodules). I am definitely not allowed (and frankly don't want to) commit CI - specific .gitmodule files (this would break developer repos), so don't even mention it please. So Jenkins can pull the main repo but instantly fails with:

```
Caused by: hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Command "git submodule update --init --recursive" returned status code 1: Cloning into blah/blah...
Host key verification failed.
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
Clone of 'ssh://server:someport/blah/blah...' into submodule path 'blah/blah' failed
```

My question: is it possible to tell Jenkins to use ssh://ci_ro@server... URL prefix for submodules instead of the configured ones in .gitmodules? Or any other workarounds, plugins, or hacks available? I looked through the job options and didn't find any useful option.

**UPDATE**

Thanks for all the help guys. The resolution was to allow the 'jenkins' system user to pull from the specific ssh server/port with git.

Comment: If you've solved your problem, please [answer your own question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16930/is-it-ok-to-answer-your-own-question-and-accept-it) and accept it, so that it helps others in the future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The resolution was to allow the system user running Jenkins to pull with SSH from the specified hosts/ports.

Comment: It means generate ssh keys for jenkins and add public key in github

Comment: Thanks alot for your solution

Answer (score 1):

You can always do it manually from a shell build step.

Comment: The build _immidiately_ hangs at the beginning, so no chance for build steps. Also, disabling recursive submodule update doesn't help.

Comment: What I mean is not to employ the plugin at all.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change /etc/ssh/ssh_config on your build server:

```
    StrictHostKeyChecking no
```

Answer (score 0):

In your build step, do a

```
git submodule init
```

then recurse through the submodules and adjust their remotes, this isn't right but the script I used when my github username changed was:

```
#!/bin/sh
git remote -v | grep richoH | while read name url type; do
    newurl=`echo $url | sed -e "s/richoH/richo/"`
    git remote set-url $name $newurl
done
```

Then do a git submodule update, which I don't believe interferes with the remotes. This is untested but I believe sound.